# Barr's element and the type-A Iwahori–Hecke algebra

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, hecke-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{S}_n$ denote the symmetric group on $n$ letters. *Barr's* element $\mathcal{S}(n) \in \Bbb{R}\bigl[ \mathfrak{S}_n \bigr]$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{S}(n) := \ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{\substack{\omega \, \in \, \mathfrak{S}_n \\ \mathrm{des}(\omega) \, \subseteq \, \{i\}}}  \omega
\end{equation}

where $\mathrm{des}(\omega) :=  \{i \mathrel\vert \omega_i > \omega_{i+1} \}$ denotes the *descent set* of the permutation $\omega = (\omega_1, \dotsc, \omega_n)$ when written in one-line notation. It is known that $S(n)$
acts semi-simply on $\Bbb{R}\bigl[\mathfrak{S}_n \bigr]$ with eigenvalues
$\sigma_k := 2^{k+1}-2$ for $0 \leq k \leq n-1$.

The elements

\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{e}_k := \prod_{j \ne k } \, {\mathcal{S}(n) - \sigma_j \over {\sigma_k - \sigma_j}}
\end{equation}

for $0 \leq k \leq n-1$ define idempotents of the group algebra. Furthermore the $\sigma_k$-eigenspace of $\mathcal{S}(n)$, namely
$\Bbb{R}\bigl[\mathfrak{S}_n \bigr]\mathfrak{e}_k$, is an invariant subspace of $\Bbb{R}\bigl[\mathfrak{S}_n\bigr]$
with respect to the left action of $\mathfrak{S}_n$. These (in general decomposable) representations are known as the *Eulerian*
representations of the symmetric group.

**Question:** Is there a proper analogue of Barr's element for the (real?) Iwahori–Hecke algebra $\mathcal{H}_n(q)$ of the symmetric group which acts semi-simply (in the left regular representation) and which gives rise to a good theory of $q$-deformed Eulerian representations?

thanks, ines.

Comment: Related, is there a descent algebra in the Hecke algebra?

Comment: When a permutation is written in one-line notation, is $\omega_1$ equal to $1$?  If not, how does one decide among the various cyclic permutations? \\ Also, TeX note: $\frak{S}_n$ `\frak{S}_n` also puts the $n$ in Fraktur font. $\mathfrak{S}_n$ `\mathfrak{S}_n` avoids this. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice: One-line notation means $\omega_1=\omega(1)$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Quite a few people, including me, have tried to define an analogue of the descent algebra for Iwahori-Hecke algebras but it doesn't seem to exist.